# boost::unordered_multimap: get all elements in bucket efficiently?

Tags: c++, boost, multimap, bucket, boost-unordered

I can get all elements in a single bucket with this code:

```
typedef boost::unordered_multimap< key, myClass*, MyHash<key> >
                                                HashMMap;
HashMMap::iterator it;
it = hashMMap_.find( someKey);
int bucketIndex = hashMMap_.bucket( someKey);
int bucketSize = hashMMap_.bucket_size( bucketIndex);

qDebug() << "index of bucket with key:" << someKey << " is:"
         << bucketIndex;
qDebug() << "number of elements in bucket with index:" << bucketIndex << " is:"
         << bucketSize;

HashMMap::local_iterator lit;
/* begin of bucket with index bucketIndex */
lit = hashMMap_.begin( bucketIndex);

for ( ; lit != sender_.hashMMap_.end( bucketIndex); ++lit) {
    qDebug() << "(*lit).first:" << (*lit).first << ", (*lit).second:" <<
               (*lit).second << ", (*lit).second->something_:" <<
               (*lit).second->something_;
}
```

I would like to get a local_iterator to the first element in a bucket and iterate over it till the bucket end, so if there is only one value for a given index in hash table (where index is the `Hash(key)`) I will iterate just through a single element and receive bucket end(), and in case of many elements I will iterate whole bucket (all values with equal hash). is this possible without `bucketIndex`, `hashMMap_.begin( bucketIndex)` and `hashMMap_.end( bucketIndex)` ?

so basically I would like to get a local_iterator like this:

```
HashMMap::local_iterator lit = hashMMap_.find_bucket_if_present( someKey);
```

---

Additional question is: do I have to test first if `find()` returns an iterator to element before  calling `int bucketIndex = hashMMap_.bucket( someKey)` ? This is what I think because explanation of `bucket()` function from boost site is:

> Returns: The index of the bucket which would contain an element with
>   key k.

```
                                 ^^^
```

I think this means I have first to `find(key)` in the multimap to know if key is present, because a call to `bucket(key)` will return an index which is not a hash but modulo of hash (`bucket_from_hash`) in the hash table under which key is stored if it is present. So because of the modulo which is done with `bucket_count`, if key was not inserted I will iterate over a virtual bucket in which it would be under current circumstances, and what is most important for me: also different hashes could be there as the bucket_count might be less than my hash (I use 16-bit `MyHash<key>` of 32-bit key as a hash function provided into multimap constructor). Is this correct?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't your code doing exactly what you're asking *already*?

Comment: probably if there is other way it would do exactly what I do with bucketIndex, but I would like to be sure that I am not missing any functionallity of this container and indeed I have to find a bucket by myself

Comment: This question appears to be better suited to codereview.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start working with ranges, like so:

```
template<typename BoostUnorderedMap, typename Key>
boost::iterator_range< typename BoostUnorderedMap::local_iterator > get_bucket_range( BoostUnorderedMap& myMap, Key const& k ) {
  int bucketIndex = myMap.bucket( k );
  return boost::iterator_range< typename BoostUnorderedMap::local_iterator >(
    myMap.begin(bucketIndex),
    myMap.end(bucketIndex)
  }
}
template<typename BoostUnorderedMap, typename Key>
boost::iterator_range< typename BoostUnorderedMap::local_const_iterator > get_bucket_range( BoostUnorderedMap const& myMap, Key const& k ) {
  int bucketIndex = myMap.bucket( k );
  return boost::iterator_range< typename BoostUnorderedMap::local_const_iterator >(
    myMap.begin(bucketIndex),
    myMap.end(bucketIndex)
  }
}
```

then, at least in C++11, you can do the following:

```
for (auto && entry : get_bucket_range( some_map, "bob" ) )
```

and it iterates over everything in the `"bob"` bucket.

While this does use `bucketIndex`, it hides these details from the end consumer, and simply gives you a `boost::range` instead.

Comment: thanks, this is nice, although I use c++03 I can still iterate using local_iterator. What about second part of my question, is it safe to call myMap.bucket( k ) without testing first if the map contains key k actually?

Comment: @piotruś I walked through the `boost` hpp files, and it led me to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/unordered/detail/hash_table.hpp where `bucket_from_hash` is the final call in a reasonably deep chain.  It hashes the key (which does not care if the key is in the map), then does `bucket_from_hash`, which just does a mod.  So at least the files I read did not require it: and I cannot think of a reason why a future implementation would want to add that requirement.

Comment: so this means I have first to find(key) in the multimap to know if key is present, because call to bucket(key) will return an index which is not a hash but modulo of hash in the hash table under which key is stored if it is present. So because of the modulo which is done with bucket_count, if key was not inserted  I will iterate over a bucket in which it would be, and also different hashes could be there as the bucket_count might be less than my hash. Correct?

Comment: @piotrus the bucket may or may not contain the key.  It is the bucket that would contain the key if it was in the map or set.  And ues, buckets are not 'everything with the same hash', they are 'everything with the same hash, or other hashes that end in this bucket'.